# Авторизироваться на сервере через андроид

Tags: android, авторизация, java

Привет! Мне нужно авторизоваться на сервере и в переменную занести то, что вернул сервер. Есть вот такой метод:

```
public String requestGET() {
    String line = null;
    StringBuffer userInfo = null;

    try {
        URL url = new URL ("http://site.ru");
        String authStr = "123456" + ":" + "123456";
        byte[] encoded = Base64.encode(authStr.getBytes(), 0);  

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestProperty  ("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
        InputStream content = (InputStream)connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader in   = 
            new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (content));

       userInfo  = new StringBuffer();

        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            userInfo.append(line);
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return userInfo.toString();
```

}

который должен работать, но он почему-то не работает.
на эмуляторе ошибка

> unfortunately has stopped

в манифесте прописал `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`. данный метод выполняю не в главном потоке приложения, а в `AsyncTask`
выбрасывает `java.lang.RuntimeException`

Ошибка:

```
05-26 20:28:48.468: E/AndroidRuntime(2043): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
05-26 20:28:48.468: E/AndroidRuntime(2043): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground() 
05-26 20:28:48.468: E/AndroidRuntime(2043): at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299) 
05-26 20:28:48.468: E/AndroidRuntime(2043): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352) 
05-26 20:28:48.468: E/AndroidRuntime(2043): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
```

Comment: Это всё, конечно же, очень интересно, но бесполезно без стэктрэйса исключения.

Comment: Ошибка

    05-26 20:28:48.468: E/AndroidRuntime(2043): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    05-26 20:28:48.468: E/AndroidRuntime(2043): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    05-26 20:28:48.468: E/AndroidRuntime(2043):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
    05-26 20:28:48.468: E/AndroidRuntime(2043):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
    05-26 20:28:48.468: E/AndroidRuntime(2043):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)

Comment: Кровавыми слезами...

Comment: Отладьте сначала в UI потоке, и уже потом засовывайте в `AsyncTask`

Comment: А потом возникнет вопрос, откуда NetworkOnMainThreadException взялся.

Comment: на любой другой сайт без проблем отправляет запрос. проблема в авторизации. byte[] encoded = Base64.encode(authStr.getBytes(), 0); скорей всего в этой строке.